# If you were born one sect (Ashkenaz) but wanted to become another (Sephardi), do you have to go through conversion?

Tags: minhag, halacha-theory, conversion-to-judaism, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi

I encountered a man who found out he was Jewish with Ashkenazi lineage, but for personal reasons converted to Sephardi. Never heard of this before. I remember learning there are several halachot in regards to staying true to your lineage/sect. I also remember lenience to when you're with a majority who hold to a different minhag.

If possible, please source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would most certainly not need a conversion, and it would not help. One of the most basic tenants of Judaism is mesorah to follow the forefathers customs. There is great discussion in the poskim what to do if one has a custom that is questionably not like halacha-see poskim shvuas-akkdamas) 
In regard to when one is with a majority that has a different custom, the halacha is one must keep his custom only when it will not be visible to others otherwise there is a problem of lo tisgodidu-not to make different camps.

Comment: Editing into your answer sources for its claims would improve its value.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no need to do so. Once a Jew always a Jew regardless of tradition preferences. As for what customs to follow... customs are traditionally passed on through the father. for a convert though what traditions to follow will be up to him. It is important though that in this journey he or she has a Rabbi that can help him or her decide which ones to keep. For the convert to find a teacher is even more important b/c of this issue. Another thing to know is that when choosing a path in Judaism that means not creating a buffet just on what seems catchy an easy thing to fall into when one doesn't have a set tradition to follow. Typically a convert will follow the customs of the Rabbi who helped him or her prepare for their conversion and if not will at least provide guidance for what they should do.